Kendo editor Angular : [vite] Internal server error: Unexpected token ':'
I have an Angular app Whenever I try to add a new UI module such as editor, I get a  [vite] Internal server error:

Unexpected token ':' error  PM [vite] Internal
server error: Unexpected token ':'
at new AsyncFunction ()
at instantiateModule (myproject/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-9A4-l-43.js:50858:28)

